# @Override claims that Method does not override, but method says it clashes with parent method

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a Queue class using a pre-written interface. The interface contains the method

```
public void enqueue(T element);
```

and my class looks like

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Queue<T> implements QueueInterface {

    ArrayList<T> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public void enqueue(T element){
        list.add(element);
    }
}
```

Currently, this results in the class generating an error saying it needs to implement the enqueue method, the override statement generates an error saying that the method doesn't override the one in my interface, and the method declaration in my class, without the override, says that it clashes with the interface's method.

Comment: Try `QueueInterface<T>`.

Comment: Is the `QueueInterface` generic?  Don't implement the raw form of that interface.

Comment: Do check warnings and errors from earlier in your code when dealing with compiler errors.

Answer (score 2):

### Here is explanation on the error:

From the code your provided, there is 2 error and 1 warning.
**Warning 1:**

> QueueInterface is a raw type. References to generic type QueueInterface should be parameterized

**Error 1:**

> The type Queue must implement the inherited abstract method QueueInterface.enqueue(Object)

**Error 2:**

> Name clash: The method enqueue(T) of type Queue has the same
>   erasure as enqueue(Object) of type QueueInterface but does not
>   override it

**Warning 1** tells that you should specify the generic type of `QueueInterface`. Without specifying the type parameter, compiler will assume you are implementing something like
`QueueInterface<Object>`(not exactly see the reference 1). Hence you see **Error 1** as there is no method implement/override `enqueue(Object)` in `Queue`.

Then why can't `enqueue(T)` override `enqueue(Object)`?
When adding `@Override` annotation to `enqueue(T element)` method, another error will show:

> The method enqueue(T) of type Queue must override or implement a
>   supertype method

This is because `enqueue(T)` is generic method and T can be any type.
For example, if we declare

```
Queue<String> stringQueue = new Queue<String>();
Queue<Integer> integerQueue = new Queue<Integer>();
```

Then `enqueue` method of `stringQueue` and `integerQueue` accept `String` and `Integer` respectively, both cannot accept `Object` as argument, and hence cannot override `enqueue(Object)`.

And finally for `Error 2`, it is quite confusing as it says that `enqueue(T)` collides with `enqueue(Object)`, but `enqueue(T)` does not override `enqueue(Object)`. These two method collide because of [erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). Which means that in **Runtime**, all `T` is replaced by `Object`. Program will not know which method to execute in this case. 
See reference 2 for details.

### Reference:

1.[What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)(**Excellent Question and Answer on Raw Type and related stuff**)

2.[Java generics type erasure: when and what happens?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339699/java-generics-type-erasure-when-and-what-happens)

Answer (score 1):

Define your `Queue` class like below with `QueuInterface` implementation.

```
    public class Queue<T> implements QueueInterface<T> {

        @Override
        public void enqueue(T element) {

        }

    }
```